# Return a row where there is only one boolean value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Below you will see there are some rows that have the same ContractID and Part Desc, but have two different types of boolean values (One row is true and the other is false). i only want to return rows where there is only a false value for the ContractID and Part Dec. If it is true, do not return, if there is a case where there is a row that is true and a row that is false, do not return. Here is what i have so far.

```
SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.ContractServices.ContractServiceID, dbo.ContractServices.ContractID, dbo.ContractServices.ServiceType, dbo.ContractServices.QuoteID, dbo.ContractServices.PartsCharge, 
                         dbo.ContractParts.PartDescription, dbo.ServiceCallCharges.ChargeDescription, dbo.ServiceCalls.ServiceCallID, dbo.ServiceCallCharges.ShowOnFieldTicket, dbo.ContractServices.Renewed
FROM            dbo.ContractServices INNER JOIN
                         dbo.ContractParts ON dbo.ContractServices.ContractServiceID = dbo.ContractParts.ContractServiceID INNER JOIN
                         dbo.ServiceCallCharges ON dbo.ServiceCallCharges.ChargeDescription LIKE '%' + dbo.ContractParts.PartDescription + '%' INNER JOIN
                         dbo.ServiceCalls ON dbo.ServiceCallCharges.ServiceCallID = dbo.ServiceCalls.ServiceCallID AND dbo.ContractServices.ContractID = dbo.ServiceCalls.ContractID AND 
                         dbo.ContractParts.ContractID = dbo.ServiceCalls.ContractID INNER JOIN
                         dbo.ServiceCallServiceTypes ON dbo.ServiceCalls.ServiceCallID = dbo.ServiceCallServiceTypes.ServiceCallID
WHERE        (dbo.ContractServices.PartsCharge > 0) AND (dbo.ServiceCallCharges.ChargeDescription LIKE '   -%') AND (dbo.ContractServices.Renewed = 'True') AND (dbo.ServiceCallCharges.ShowOnInvoice = 'False')
GROUP BY dbo.ContractServices.ContractServiceID, dbo.ContractServices.ContractID, dbo.ContractServices.ServiceType, dbo.ContractServices.QuoteID, dbo.ContractServices.PartsCharge, dbo.ContractParts.PartDescription, 
                         dbo.ServiceCallCharges.ChargeDescription, dbo.ServiceCalls.ServiceCallID, dbo.ServiceCallCharges.ShowOnFieldTicket, dbo.ContractServices.Renewed
ORDER BY dbo.ContractServices.ContractID
```

some of the output i want to get rid of looks like this:

```
177633  S00304  LEVEL2  3   126.6700    SAMPLE, OIL    - SAMPLE, OIL    True    True
177633  S00304  LEVEL2  3   126.6700    SAMPLE, OIL    - SAMPLE, OIL    False   True


198559  S00369  SERVICE 6   240.6800    FILTER, FUEL       - FILTER, FUEL   True    True
198559  S00369  SERVICE 6   240.6800    FILTER, FUEL       - FILTER, FUEL   False   True
```

as you can see everything is the same except for the one field. If this occurs i want to remove it from the view. i only want to return values that only have a false in that particular field. What is the logic that needs to go into this query to make this happen?

Comment: Do you know that 3 and 4 part naming of columns is deprecated? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510662%28v=sql.110%29.aspx If you used aliases in this query it will be less than half as many characters as it is currently. I realize this doesn't answer your question but it would help you write more manageable queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WITH cte2 AS (SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT ContractServices_1.ContractServiceID, ContractServices_1.ContractID, ContractServices_1.ServiceType, ContractServices_1.QuoteID, ContractParts_1.PartDescription, 
                                                         ServiceCallCharges_1.ChargeDescription, ServiceCalls_1.ServiceCallID, ServiceCallCharges_1.ShowOnFieldTicket, ContractServices_1.Renewed
                                FROM            dbo.ContractServices AS ContractServices_1 INNER JOIN
                                                         dbo.ContractParts AS ContractParts_1 ON ContractServices_1.ContractServiceID = ContractParts_1.ContractServiceID INNER JOIN
                                                         dbo.ServiceCallCharges AS ServiceCallCharges_1 ON ServiceCallCharges_1.ChargeDescription LIKE '%' + ContractParts_1.PartDescription + '%' INNER JOIN
                                                         dbo.ServiceCalls AS ServiceCalls_1 ON ServiceCallCharges_1.ServiceCallID = ServiceCalls_1.ServiceCallID AND ContractServices_1.ContractID = ServiceCalls_1.ContractID AND 
                                                         ContractParts_1.ContractID = ServiceCalls_1.ContractID
                                WHERE        (ServiceCallCharges_1.ChargeDescription LIKE '   -%' OR
                                                         ServiceCallCharges_1.ChargeDescription LIKE '%') AND (ServiceCallCharges_1.ShowOnFieldTicket = 'True') AND (ContractServices_1.Renewed = 'True')
                                GROUP BY ContractServices_1.ContractServiceID, ContractServices_1.ContractID, ContractServices_1.ServiceType, ContractServices_1.QuoteID, ContractParts_1.PartDescription, 
                                                         ServiceCallCharges_1.ChargeDescription, ServiceCalls_1.ServiceCallID, ContractServices_1.Renewed, ServiceCallCharges_1.ShowOnFieldTicket
                                ORDER BY ContractServices_1.ContractID), cte1 AS
    (SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.ContractServices.ContractServiceID, dbo.ContractServices.ContractID, dbo.ContractServices.ServiceType, dbo.ContractServices.QuoteID, dbo.ContractParts.PartDescription, 
                                dbo.ServiceCallCharges.ChargeDescription, dbo.ServiceCalls.ServiceCallID, dbo.ServiceCallCharges.ShowOnFieldTicket, dbo.ContractServices.Renewed
      FROM            dbo.ContractServices INNER JOIN
                                dbo.ContractParts ON dbo.ContractServices.ContractServiceID = dbo.ContractParts.ContractServiceID INNER JOIN
                                dbo.ServiceCallCharges ON dbo.ServiceCallCharges.ChargeDescription LIKE '%' + dbo.ContractParts.PartDescription + '%' INNER JOIN
                                dbo.ServiceCalls ON dbo.ServiceCallCharges.ServiceCallID = dbo.ServiceCalls.ServiceCallID AND dbo.ContractServices.ContractID = dbo.ServiceCalls.ContractID AND 
                                dbo.ContractParts.ContractID = dbo.ServiceCalls.ContractID
      WHERE        (dbo.ServiceCallCharges.ChargeDescription LIKE '   -%' OR
                                dbo.ServiceCallCharges.ChargeDescription LIKE '%') AND (dbo.ServiceCallCharges.ShowOnFieldTicket = 'False') AND (dbo.ContractServices.Renewed = 'True')
      GROUP BY dbo.ContractServices.ContractServiceID, dbo.ContractServices.ContractID, dbo.ContractServices.ServiceType, dbo.ContractServices.QuoteID, dbo.ContractParts.PartDescription, 
                                dbo.ServiceCallCharges.ChargeDescription, dbo.ServiceCalls.ServiceCallID, dbo.ContractServices.Renewed, dbo.ServiceCallCharges.ShowOnFieldTicket
      ORDER BY dbo.ContractServices.ContractID)
    SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT cte1_1.ContractServiceID, cte1_1.ContractID, cte1_1.ServiceType, cte1_1.QuoteID, cte1_1.PartDescription, cte1_1.ChargeDescription, cte1_1.ServiceCallID, cte1_1.ShowOnFieldTicket, 
                              cte1_1.Renewed
     FROM            cte1 AS cte1_1 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                              cte2 AS cte2_1 ON cte1_1.PartDescription = cte2_1.PartDescription AND cte1_1.ContractID = cte2_1.ContractID
     WHERE        (cte2_1.ShowOnFieldTicket IS NULL)
     GROUP BY cte1_1.ContractServiceID, cte1_1.ContractID, cte1_1.ServiceType, cte1_1.QuoteID, cte1_1.PartDescription, cte1_1.ChargeDescription, cte1_1.ServiceCallID, cte1_1.ShowOnFieldTicket, cte1_1.Renewed, 
                              cte2_1.ShowOnFieldTicket
     ORDER BY cte1_1.ContractID
```

Comment: this is my answer. i created two cte so i could compare when an id was true and when it was false, as well, so i could retrieve data where an id was only false.

Answer (score 0):

you can try the below query:

```
SELECT 
ContractServiceID, 
ContractID, 
ServiceType, 
QuoteID, 
PartsCharge,  
PartDescription,
ChargeDescription,
ServiceCallID,
'False' as ShowOnFieldTicket,
Renewed
FROM
(
SELECT  DISTINCT
    dbo.ContractServices.ContractServiceID, 
    dbo.ContractServices.ContractID, 
    dbo.ContractServices.ServiceType, 
    dbo.ContractServices.QuoteID, 
    dbo.ContractServices.PartsCharge, 
    dbo.ContractParts.PartDescription, 
    dbo.ServiceCallCharges.ChargeDescription, 
    dbo.ServiceCalls.ServiceCallID, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.ServiceCallCharges.ShowOnFieldTicket = 'True' THEN 1 ELSE NULL)  
        OVER (PARTITION BY dbo.ContractServices.ContractServiceID, dbo.ContractServices.ContractID ORDER BY dbo.ContractServices.ContractID) as ShowOnFieldTicket
    dbo.ContractServices.Renewed
FROM   
    dbo.ContractServices 
        INNER JOIN dbo.ContractParts 
            ON dbo.ContractServices.ContractServiceID = dbo.ContractParts.ContractServiceID 
        INNER JOIN dbo.ServiceCallCharges 
            ON dbo.ServiceCallCharges.ChargeDescription LIKE '%' + dbo.ContractParts.PartDescription + '%' 
        INNER JOIN dbo.ServiceCalls 
            ON dbo.ServiceCallCharges.ServiceCallID = dbo.ServiceCalls.ServiceCallID 
                AND dbo.ContractServices.ContractID = dbo.ServiceCalls.ContractID 
                AND dbo.ContractParts.ContractID = dbo.ServiceCalls.ContractID 
        INNER JOIN dbo.ServiceCallServiceTypes 
            ON dbo.ServiceCalls.ServiceCallID = dbo.ServiceCallServiceTypes.ServiceCallID
WHERE 
    (dbo.ContractServices.PartsCharge > 0) AND 
    (dbo.ServiceCallCharges.ChargeDescription LIKE '   -%') AND 
    (dbo.ContractServices.Renewed = 'True') AND 
    (dbo.ServiceCallCharges.ShowOnInvoice = 'False')

) T
WHERE ShowOnFieldTicket is NULL
ORDER BY ContractID
```

Comment: sorry for the late response. this still gave me a result set that returned data with contracts ids that had a true and a false for the same part description.